# how to make a 100% width, 100% height large table inside a display table cell div scroll instead of the whole page

Tags: css

I have a page layout like this:

```
<div class="LayoutTable">
   <div class="LayoutTableRow Header">
      <div class="LayoutTableCell Header">            
         <h1 class="InterfaceName">Item</h1>            
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="LayoutTableRow Main">
      <div class="LayoutTableCell">
         <div class="GridTableWrapper">


            <!-- A large inner table goes here -->


         </div><!-- GridTableWrapper -->
      </div><!-- LayoutTableCell-->
   </div><!-- LayoutTableRow-->

   <div class="LayoutTableRow Footer">
      <div class="LayoutTableCell Footer">         
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The header and footer rows have a fixed height of 49px, and the middle section, being display:table-cell, fills the remaining space. This part works fine, until you add the data table inside the layout "table" divs.

What should happen is, however big the cell of the layout table is, should stay that size, and the data table, being too large, should have scroll bars to scroll it *within* the layout table's cell.

Instead, no matter what I try, the browser insists on blowing up the layout table so the entire data table can fit in the cell. The result is the scroll bars get applied to the whole page, instead of to the cell with the table.

I can accomplish this by specifying widths in pixels, but the goal is to do this using a fluid layout.

How do I make it so the cell is what gets scrolled, so the footer and header are visible at all times and the left-right scroll is also at the layout cell level rather than the page level?

I've Created a fiddle of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/hhUnH/2/

Comment: <table> expands , they do not scroll :) unless you modify their default display; and then, they do not really behaves like tables , cols may break.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to put it would be to have the div in the layout cell be 100% of the cells size, and it has scroll bars for the table inside of it?

Comment: this won't work, cause the cell fills empty room left behind header and footer, and then grows if needed. your height:100% .The height of that table-cell could be anything , (content, window-size, ..) , this a value that the div can not inherit to use, because it is not clearly written in CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

If

1. it's a full page layout,
2. that your header are nothing more than containers(not thead but 
   header )
3. that your footer are nothing more than containers(not tfoot but
   footer )
4. that header and footer have a known height,

Then you may set a table into an absolute container.
http://jsfiddle.net/hhUnH/4/

```
   #tableContainer  {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:49px;
    bottom:49px;
    }
```

If these datas are datas to read in 2D, then use a table, else is a mixed salad ot tags :)

Comment: That works, but technically, it's cheating. You're absolutely positioning the table in a spot where the hole for it will be, but without determining the dimensions based on the actual hole it fits into. If the middle row of the layout table had two cells, there would be know way to fit the table using this method, unless one of the cells was fixed.

Comment: it is not cheating, it's one of the purpose of absolute positionning. There's no magic, else (cheat lol) using javascript to get height sized of window. do not forget onresize as well ;) ++